# Passing large values to modules

Tags: arrays, perl, module, subroutine

I had a program that was slow, and was trying to improve performance. The script "use"s a sub in a module, and passes an array that's quite large to the sub. After some tinkering, I realized if I moved the sub directly into the parent script, and made the array global instead of local (so I didn't have to pass it), the script was massively faster (running in minutes where it was taking days).

I'd really like to be able to have that sub in the module (because I have many scripts that call that same sub). But I'd also like it to be fast. :-)

Semi-pseudocode

page.pl:

```
package Page;

use Star;
my @fileBytes=();
open(StarFile, "<$File");
binmode(StarFile);
while (read(StarFile, $FileValues, 1)) {
  push @fileBytes, $FileValues; 
}
close(StarFile);

&parseBlock(\@fileBytes);
```

Module.pl:

```
package Star;

sub parseBlock {
  my ($fileBytes) = @_;
  my @fileBytes = @{ $fileBytes };

  ...
}
```

Some reading here: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Variable%20Scoping%20in%20Perl%3A%20the%20basics tells me I want to deal with scoping. So if I define @fileBytes with "our" instead of "my" it becomes a package value. As best I can tell, that would normally be in the module file. But i'm starting with the value in the parent.

So I can make the parent also a package, define:
our @fileBytes

and then reference it from the module as at least something like:
@Page::fileBytes

I think I have that at least right in theory.

My problem appears when I want to use the sub from a different script:

other.pl:

```
package Other;
use Star;

  my @fileBytes=();
  open(StarFile, "<$File");
  binmode(StarFile);
  while (read(StarFile, $FileValues, 1)) {
    push @fileBytes, $FileValues; 
  }
  close(StarFile);

&parseBlock(\@fileBytes, $offset);
```

Now the value I'm passing is @Other::fileBytes . That problem expands the more I use my library.

What i'd like to be able to do is have the subroutine in the module, but not have to pass (which I believe is creating a new value, which must be slow) the @fileBytes data because it's "global", in such a way as I can use the centralized sub.

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope. You are passing an arrayreference to `parseBlock()` which is fine because it allows the subroutine to access this data directly. In your subs second line you copy the array content which might be unnecessary and in case of huge data unfortunate, but very unlikely to account for the performance difference that you describe (minutes vs. days). See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut)

Comment: One easy and reasonable thing to do is to _not_ create a local array in the sub, `my @fileBytes = @{ $fileBytes };` ---  but instead use `$fileBytes` arrayref  (unless that array gets changed in the sub!).  That data copy takes time if the array is large, of course.  I still don't see how that makes minutes into days though, unless the sub is called many many times...

Comment: I would suggest to not tinker with making things `our`  ... you want a sub that takes the data it needs.  If there is a legitimate problem with the data size then you need to reconsider the approach, not start making things global.

Answer (score 7):

You can't pass arrays to subs, only scalars. When one uses `f(@a)`, one is passing the elements of the array. This doesn't create any new scalars or make copies of any of the scalars, so it's actually pretty fast nonetheless.

However, even that small cost can be avoided. This is done by passing a reference to an array: `f(\@a)`. This does create a single scalar, but it's the lightest of them all.

This is what you're already doing, so from the point of view of calling the sub, you already have the fastest. The problem you are facing is the result of what you do immediately after the sub is called: You create a new array and copy every element of the provided array into this new array.

```perl
my @fileBytes = @{ $fileBytes };  # Copies every element.
```

Remove that line, and your problem is fixed. Of course, you'll need to change any code that used the duplicate array (`@fileBytes`) to use the original array (`@$fileBytes`) instead. The only caveat is that any changes to the array will be reflected in the array passed via reference to the sub, since it's the same array.

---

**Alternative Solution**

If you insist on avoiding working with references, you can use the following:

```perl
use experimental qw( declared_refs );

my \@fileBytes = $fileBytes;
```

The effectively makes `@fileBytes` an alias for `@$fileBytes`. No copying is involved. It's not free, but it's not expensive either (O(1)). Just as with modifying `@$filesBytes` directly, modifying `@fileBytes` will affect the array in the caller.

Generally speaking, one should avoid experimental code in production, but the devs are planning to enable it by default in the next major version of Perl, so they surely consider it quite stable.